# Reusing custom UITableViewCells, see old UIView pictures briefly before new pictures load

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview, reuseidentifier

I have a custom UITableViewCell that contains a UIView, in which I display a couple of pictures.

In my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: function, I call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to reuse old custom cells, and then I update them with new pictures.

The problem is that when I scroll quickly on my screen, I see flickers of the old pictures before the new ones are loaded, which is unattractive.

I've tried to fix this by:

- implementing prepareForReuse in the custom TableViewCell implementation file; this led to the same three UIViews appearing over and over again, and in this case the new pictures stopped loading altogether
- clearing the UIView right after calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier by using a for loop to remove all subviews; the app now takes a really long time to load pictures.

What is the best way to fix this, and why do the above errors in my attempted fixes occur? Here is my current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Blah";
    blahCell *someCell = (blahCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!someCell) {
        //initialize cell
    } else {

        someCell.imageContainerView = nil;
    }

    ... (other code here)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `UIImageView` **Category** by [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking).

Whenever you have to set a new image you just need to call

```
[someCell.imageContainerView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:placeholderImage];
```

Now, whenever you scroll, if the image is not loaded you will see a placeholder image instead of seeing previous cell images.

Comment: I am already using this to set my images, and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting the cell's imageView property to `nil` as the first step in your table view data source method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I've been trying that, but it hasn't been working. I've updated my question to include my current code